# NSAttributedString in iOS 5 setting text font and background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set attributes in NSAttributedString in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441934/how-to-set-attributes-in-nsattributedstring-in-ios)

I have the following code:

```
 comment = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.highlightItem_.comment];
            [comment addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:kProximaNovaBold size:15] range:nameRange];
            [comment addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:128/255.f green:203/255.f blue:255/255.f alpha:1.0] range:nameRange];

            [comment addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:kProximaNova size:15] range:commentRange];
            [comment addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithWhite:153/255.f alpha:1.0] range:commentRange];
```

This is however an iOS 6 code, what if I want to do the same in iOS 5. Do I have to use a third party library for this?

Comment: see my this answer may be its useful to you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579209/two-colors-for-uilabel-text/13579318#13579318

Comment: This code will also work on iOS 5.0, NSMutableAttributedString available from iOS 3.2

Comment: @Ishu the NSFontAttributeName won't work actually

Comment: @ParasJoshi is there a way to setup the font on CoreText?

Comment: @adit hey that code is for CoreText just see this tutorial from my that answer also.. http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/06/coretext-tutorial-for-ios-part-1.html :)

Comment: @adit you try my answer ??

Comment: To support ios 5 and lower, use [OHAttributedLabel][1]. 


  [1]: https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could drop down into Core Text for iOS 5. Core Text is more powerful than `NSAttributedString` but it's also less documented and less accessible to engineers.